# Custom Pager throwing undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var pagerID = $(this).attr("data-pagerID");
$.tablesorter.customPagerControls({
            table          : $('#'+id),                // point at correct table (string or jQuery object)
            pager          : $('#'+pagerID),           // pager wrapper (string or jQuery object)
            pageSize       : '.left a',                // container for page sizes
            currentPage    : '.right a',               // container for page selectors
            ends           : 2,                        // number of pages to show of either end
            aroundCurrent  : 1,                        // number of pages surrounding the current page
            link           : '<a href="#">{page}</a>', // page element; use {page} to include the page number
            currentClass   : 'current',                // current page class name
            adjacentSpacer : ' | ',                    // spacer for page numbers next to each other
            distanceSpacer : ' \u2026 '                // spacer for page numbers away from each other (ellipsis &hellip;)
        });
```

For some reason, the above code (taken from http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/beta-testing/example-pager-custom-controls.

The error is throwing at:

```
$.tablesorter.customPagerControls
```

From digging, it appears that customPagerControls doesn't exist in the JS.

Comment: Have you loaded `pager-custom-controls.js`?

Comment: I may have missed that. Didn't see anything listed in the example code either. It is however hidden in the page source. However, it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Undefined is still not a function.

Comment: Looks like pager-custom-controls was an important part. There are some more nuances to the issue. I have created a separate question to deal with these. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805547/appying-a-custom-pager-to-multiple-tables-in-tabs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed to import the pager-custom-controls.js file located in the beta-testing package director.